# Enabling html 5 mode for Angular JS throws JS error: Failed to instantiate module due to: TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Mode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I enable html 5 mode for Angular JS?

```
'use strict'

var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/disclaimer', { templateUrl: 'templates/disclaimer.html', controller:         'DisclaimerCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

When I add the line about html5mode, I get the following JS error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module blogApp due to:
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Mode' of undefined

I'm using Angular 1.2.15 on IIS

Comment: $locationProvider is not declared in injections list (in config(), before function declaration).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`config(['$routeProvider',` is missing  `$locationProvider` declaration on the array.

```
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```